# UDP client in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I use the code on http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html

the code works fine, I can see that the message is sent and the server receives it. However, When I build the program, I get the following "passing argument 5 of ‘sendto’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" for the line "`if (sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1){`". I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to fix. thank you

```
    #define  MAXSTRINGLENGTH 128
#define BUFSIZE 512

void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop);
    void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char hello[] = "hello bitches";
    char next_hop[]= "192.168.1.178";
    log_msg_send(hello, next_hop);
}

void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop){
    char SRV_IP[16]; 
    strcpy(SRV_IP,  next_hop);

         struct sockaddr_in si_other;
         int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
         char buf[50] ;
         strcpy(buf, message);

        if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1){
          fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
          exit(1);
        }

        memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
        si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
        si_other.sin_port = htons(33333);
        if (inet_aton(SRV_IP, &si_other.sin_addr)==0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
          exit(1);
        }
          printf("Sending the packet %d\n", i);
          if (sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1){
          fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
          exit(1);
        }

        close(s);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, slen)
```

This conversion is required because [`sendto()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sendto) expects a pointer to `struct sockaddr` as its fifth argument while your particular socket address type is `struct sockaddr_in`.

Answer (score 3):

From the POSIX docs:

```
ssize_t sendto(int socket, const void *message, size_t length,
   int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr,
   socklen_t dest_len);
```

So the 5th argument of `sendto()` is supposed to be a `struct sockaddr *`. However, you're passing it a (memory layout-compatible) `struct sockadd_in *`. The fix: cast it to the appropriate pointer type:

```
sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, slen)
```

Answer (score 3):

please check this:

```
sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&si_other, slen)
```

where:

```
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sendto(s,buf,BUFSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*) &si_other, (socklen_t) slen)
```

It works for me!